# Is It Possible To Create a .jar File That Runs An Existing .bat File?

Tags: java, batch-file, jar, executable, executable-jar

I have a .bat file that I need to run from a .jar executable. I have looked around and can find no obvious way of doing so... Is there anyway this can be done? Help! Here is my existing .bat code if it helps:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: When setting the memory below make sure to include the amount of ram   
::      letter. M = MB, G = GB. Don't use 1GB for example, it's 1G ::

:: This is 64-bit memory ::
set memsixtyfour=2G

:: This is 32-bit memory - maximum 1.2G ish::
set memthirtytwo=1G

:: Don't edit past this point ::

if $SYSTEM_os_arch==x86 (
  echo OS is 32
  set mem=%memthirtytwo%
) else (
  echo OS is 64
  set mem=%memsixtyfour%
)
java -Xmx%mem% -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar forge-1.7.10-10.13.2.1277-universal.jar nogui
PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Runtime class that can make System calls.

This is the code i would use :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start your/path/yourbat.bat");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your java code.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start filename.bat");
```

Comment: Sorry, as a complete beginner when it comes to java, I don't really know where to begin, to do this. Is there a file I need to create in a notepad file etc... thank you

Comment: You create your jar file from the java application. So you should have some java files. You have to modify the java file that tries to run the bat file. If this is not clear yet could you please share your java code.

Comment: `package com.example.helloworld;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by Bob on 12/06/2015.
 */
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start C:\\Users\\Bob\\Desktop\\ModdedServer\\MinecrackNetwork\\LaunchServer.bat");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
`

Comment: This is my current code, which successfully launches the .bat file. However, when the .bat is launched the console reads that the.bat file cannot locate the files it needs to run. Whereas running the .bat file normally finds these files fine, and runs successfully.

Comment: According to your comment I can say that your initial query has been solved. About your second query try modifying your bat file code and add this line into your bat file:     java -jar %~dp0yourjarfile.jar %*